# Запуск тестов через Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, юнит-тесты, поток-ввода

Все тесты в программе при запуске из класса работают правильно. Но при запуске через Maven генерируются файлы с подобными ошибками:

```
# Created at 2020-11-12T01:11:12.039
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:283)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:100)
    at java.util.Scanner.readInput(Scanner.java:804)
    at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Scanner.java:1685)
    at java.util.Scanner.hasNextLine(Scanner.java:1500)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.PpidChecker$ProcessInfoConsumer.execute(PpidChecker.java:354)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.PpidChecker.unix(PpidChecker.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.PpidChecker.isProcessAlive(PpidChecker.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter$2.run(ForkedBooter.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


# Created at 2020-11-12T01:11:12.042
System.exit() or native command error interrupted process checker.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: error [STOPPED] to read process 20979
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.PpidChecker.checkProcessInfo(PpidChecker.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.PpidChecker.isProcessAlive(PpidChecker.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter$2.run(ForkedBooter.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.example.communication.CommunicationApplicationTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 32.317 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.communication.CommunicationApplicationTests
contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.008 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerUtils' defined in file [/home/friday58/IdeaProjects/communication/target/classes/com/example/communication/controller/ControllerUtils.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storage' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/storage/GcpStorageAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.storage.Storage]: Factory method 'storage' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storage' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/storage/GcpStorageAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.storage.Storage]: Factory method 'storage' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.storage.Storage]: Factory method 'storage' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка ввода-вывода при попытке чтения с помощью `java.util.Scanner`.

Если тесты работают нормально в программе при запуске из класса, то программа может определить однозначно источник данных, если он является файлом и указан относительный путь.

При запуске из Maven путь будет определяться оттуда откуда он запускается и тогда уже относительный путь будет другой.

Поэтому надо  указать абсолютный путь к файлу при создании потока.

Comment: Вы не подскажите, где именно нужно указать абсолютный путь к файлу? И что конкретно Вы подразумеваете под файлом?

Comment: Для этого нужно смотреть исходные тексты кода.

Comment: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.